# Perform an Action on showing AlertDialoge, then dismiss

Tags: java, android

I would like to start an AlertDialogue showing a loading message and a ProgressBar icon, then on showing the dialogue I would run the heavy processing with the ProgressBar spinning, and finally cancel the dialogue when the processing is over.

I have tried putting the logic on setOnShowListener of the alert dialogue which was not carried out. Then, I have tried starting the dialogue then using a delayed handler like the following:

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
    // heavy procssing logic
    // alert.dismiss();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Though, the ProgressBar icon stopped spinning, so I assumed that my heavy processing blocked the UI. How do I achieve what I need. Thanks.

Edit: I have replaced the handler with new Thread() and everything worked properly. Would this approach cause any problems like memory leaks?

Comment: New Thread method would be fine. But preferred method in android would be to use AsyncTask and show the dialog inside onPreExecute() method and do the heavy processing inside doInBackground() and hide the dialog inside onPostExecute() method.

Comment: Thank for your the information, Mohammed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new AsyncTask to do your work, this will cause any code placed in the “doInBackground()” method to be ran in a background thread, you have pre-execute and post-execute to run code on the main thread, my recommendation is create an alertDialog in the pre-execute methods and close it on the post-execute, using “publishProgress()” method In the doInBackground method to update your dialog as you need.

Otherwise instead of an alertDialog (or as well as) you can use a progressBar, simply have it in the view preciously, instantiate it as you normally would.

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id=“+id/progressBar”
  android:layout_width=“wrap_content”
  android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
  android:centreInParent=true
  android:indeterminate=true
  android:visibility=gone />

ProgressBar progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
```

Now when you want to show the progress bar use

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(visible)
```

Or to hide

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(gone)
```

Comment: I decided to go with the Thread solution myself. Though, it seems more people agree on the AsynTask approach. So, I have picked this as the answer. Thank you.